# PLSQL nested for loops over tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables that contains employee information.

`emp1 (emp1_id, emp1_name)`

and

`emp2 (emp2_id, emp2_name)`.

I want to compare if the Employee names in emp1 exists in emp2. So I would like to write a PLSQL procedure which executes the following pseudocode:

```
for each emp1_name in emp1 from first_row...to...last_row LOOP
   for each emp2_name in emp2 from first_row...to...last_row LOOP
       check emp1_name = emp2_name
   END LOOP

   if emp1_name is not equal to ANY emp2_name
     dbms.output "the employee name doesn't exist in emp2"

END LOOP
```

Comment: do you have to use nested Loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a list of names that exist in `emp1` and not in `emp2`, you could use following SQL query:

```
SELECT emp1_name as emp_name FROM emp1
 MINUS
SELECT emp2_name as emp_name FROM emp2
```

If you also need the id by those name, you can make following query:

```
SELECT emp1_id, emp1_name FROM emp1
 WHERE emp1_name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT emp2_name FROM emp2)
```

If you really need a PL/SQL procedure for some reason, for example your boss is telling you so, you can take that SQL query and just put it in procedure:

If you just need to get DBMS_OUTPUT for some reason:

```
BEGIN

FOR i IN (SELECT emp1_id, emp1_name FROM emp1
           WHERE emp1_name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT emp2_name FROM emp2))
LOOP
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE('the employee name ' ||i.emp1_name|| ' with id '||i.emp1_id||' doesn''t exist in emp2');
END LOOP;

END;
```

If you need the resulting query, but it just has to be in procedure/function, you can also take either one of two queries I wrote and put it inside a PIPELINE function and then getting out the data that way.'

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DelinMathew No problem. Can you please rate the answer and select it as correct if it truly helped you? Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could've helped :)